# How to mix android.support.v4.app.Fragment and android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, nokia, here-api, nokiax

I'm having a problem with com.here.android.mapping.MapFragment when trying to use it with tabs.

The issue comes that since the TabActivity is deprecated(I know it still works, but need a future proof solution), and FragmentTabHost appears to be requiring the v4 fragment to be used (it crashes if the fragment is derived from other one) , then when I try having the com.here.android.mapping.MapFragment used in a layout of one of the tab fragments, then I can not retrieve it for the required initialization, since the (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById() line has error indicating that the casting to MapFragment can not be made.

I suppose the issue is that MapFragment is derived from android.app.Fragment and the findFragmentById expects to return mix android.support.v4.app.Fragment, so the question would be on how could I get this mixture to run smoothly together ?

Comment: Somebody edited this to be Googlemaps, but indeed this is HERE Maps question, for NokiaX platform, thus re-corrected the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and the `android.app.Fragment` classes can't be used interchangeably.

Nokia have created [com.here.android.mapping.MapCompatibilityFragment](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/_zip/javadocs_here_developer_guide_v1.2/com/here/android/mapping/MapCompatibilityFragment.html) which extends     `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` - use that instead if your app uses support fragments.